# single-customposttype.php showing multiple posts while using CPT UI

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the CPT UI plugin to create Custom Posts.
I have included the single-challenge.php in my theme directory. Code is below:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'challenge');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```

But is showing up all the posts, but no the single post. Any idea what is the problem?

Thanks,
Akif

Comment: when you click on some post, it shows all the posts?

Comment: Yes. Even from admin, when click on 'View Challenge', it shows all challenges.